# Ссылка по верх iframe / JS / JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать ссылку по верх iframe, а точнее:

iframe содержит видео ролик с Youtube, как разместить (наложить) ссылку по верх iframe, на всю ширину и высоту iframe, и при нажатии на ссылку посетителя перебрасывает на другой сайт, а сама ссылка исчезает и видео становится доступным (активным) для просмотра.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо!

```
<a id="iframe_link" href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"></a>
<iframe id="iframe_video" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyCcXDir0Eg" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: Оборачиваете это все в див, делаете прозрачный оверлай при клики на который будет переадресация пользователя. Z-index оверлею делаете больше, чем у фрейма.

Comment: Спасибо! Можно пример пожалуйста, спасибо.

Comment: Пример в CodePen: https://codepen.io/dovgaldmitriy/pen/xxmJgLG

Answer (score -1):

Ну, вообщем нашкодил вот такой код и ещё втулил изображение )))
Если у кого будет более внятное решение, пожалуйста поделитесь )))

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".media_box").on({
        click: function() {
            $(this).hide(); 
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.media_url {
    position:relative;
    top:500px;
    left:0px;
}
.media_img {
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="media_box">
    <a class="media_url" href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">
        <img class="media_img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QyCcXDir0Eg/hqdefault.jpg" />
    </a>
</div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyCcXDir0Eg" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```